# I'm having issue on send time span from from end to web api

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Here I'm finding time difference between two dates and number of hours get calculated like this.

```js
var startdate = $filter('date')(addTeamtask.startdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
            var enddate = $filter('date')(addTeamtask.duedate, 'yyyy-MM-dd  23:59:59');
            var sYear = startdate.slice(0, 4);
            var eYear = enddate.slice(0, 4);
            if (sYear > eYear) { var year = sYear - eYear; var yearhour = year * 8640; } else { year = eYear - sYear; yearhour = year * 8640; }
            var sMonth = startdate.slice(5, 7);
            var eMonth = enddate.slice(5, 7);
            if (sMonth > eMonth) { var month = sMonth - eMonth; var monthhour = month * 720; } else { month = eMonth - sMonth; monthhour = month * 720; }
            var Sday = startdate.slice(8, 10);
            var Eday = enddate.slice(8, 10);
            if (Sday > Eday) { var day = Sday - Eday; var hours = day * 24; } else { day = Eday - Sday; hours = day * 24 }
            
            var totalhours1 = yearhour + monthhour + hours;
           var totalhours = totalhours1 +'59:59.544';
```

But while i send this hours on string format to my web API, it shows {00:00:00} i.e actually time is not binding, Where as if i manually insert hours like this.

```js
 var totalhours = "15:58:50.373"
```

On my API show time as what i had send {15:58:50.373}. So Somebody help me how i may send time dynamically.

Comment: what happened when you statically bind your datetime?

Comment: Date time sends successfully on this format "StartDate":"2016-03-29  12:00:00",

Comment: Have you console.log `totalHours1`?

Comment: yes, maybe that's where the problem is..try to debug your object.

Comment: @ Pierre C.,Yes, in console log shows   totalhours:"72:59:59.544"

Comment: @ Bharat, Thanks, i'm still doing that

Comment: Dont you think "72:59:59.544" is not a proper datetime?

Comment: yes,this is proper time but i can't get this time over my API, that is my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had fix my issue on my own way. like this

```js
var startdate = $filter('date')(addTeamtask.startdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
            var enddate = $filter('date')(addTeamtask.duedate, 'yyyy-MM-dd  23:59:59');
            var sYear = startdate.slice(0, 4);
            var eYear = enddate.slice(0, 4);
            if (sYear > eYear) { var year = sYear - eYear; var yearhour = year * 8640; } else { year = eYear - sYear; yearhour = year * 8640; }
            var sMonth = startdate.slice(5, 7);
            var eMonth = enddate.slice(5, 7);
            if (sMonth > eMonth) { var month = sMonth - eMonth; var monthhour = month * 720; } else { month = eMonth - sMonth; monthhour = month * 720; }
            var Sday = startdate.slice(8, 10);
            var Eday = enddate.slice(8, 10);
            if (Sday > Eday) { var day = Sday - Eday; var hours = day * 24; } else { day = Eday - Sday; hours = day * 24 }
            
            var totalhours1 = yearhour + monthhour + hours;
           var totalhours = totalhours1 +'59:59.544';
           var totalHoursCaluclutation=totalhours.tostring();
```

Now API accept my request...  Thanks for your commands. Kindly keep support me.